# compare two arrayList and stock the result in a thirth arrayList

Tags: java, networking

i want compare 2 arrayList when i stock in them the result of a class java of telnet
this class it's to telnet about a router and gives all of interfaces of this routers then stock them in the arrayList
so i stock the interfaces for the router1 in myData1 and the second in myData2
and i will compare if the interface of the first aray it's the same in the second just add one of them in the array of result myData
but it gives me anthing the code

```
public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;
     try { 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mohammedia", "root", "123456"); 
String sql = "SELECT * FROM router;"; 
          Telnet_Interface telnet = new Telnet_Interface();
          Telnet_Interface telnet1 = new Telnet_Interface();
          Telnet_Interface telnet2 = new Telnet_Interface();
            PreparedStatement prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet res=prest.executeQuery();
            while(res.next()){
telnet1.Config(res.getString(1), "user", "passwd", res.getString(1));
telnet2.Config(res.getString(2), "user", "passwd", res.getString(2));
            }
           ArrayList myData=new ArrayList();
           ArrayList myData1=telnet1.getMyData();
           ArrayList myData2=telnet2.getMyData();
      boolean bool=false;            
  for(int i=0;i<myData1.size();i++)    
  {    
     for(int j=0;j<myData2.size();j++)    
    {
        if (myData2.get(j).equals(myData1.get(i)))
             {                
                bool=true; 
                //System.out.print("sdfsd");
             }

    if(!bool)
        {
            myData.add(myData2.get(j));
            //System.out.print("sdsd");
        }      
  }
  }
  for(int x=0;x<myData.size();x++)
  {
      System.out.print(myData.get(x));
  }

     } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
     }       
}

}
```

what's the problem ??
thank you

Comment: You use `.equals()`; does your `TelnetInterface` implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` correctly?

Comment: Do you want to keep all the distinct elements of both List in a separate List ?

Comment: If `Telnet_Interface` is user defined class then override the `equals` method in that class ..

Comment: @VishalK _and_ `.hashCode()`

Comment: @fge: Since user is not using the `collections` based on `hashCode` for storing `Telnet_Interface` object , so I don't think it is needed in this case.

Comment: @VishalK that is not the question of thinking or not; if you don't implement `.hashCode()` you break the `.equals()` contract (two equal objects must have the same hash code).

Comment: @fge: You are absolutely right in what you said. What I wanted to say that For this case `hashcode` is not required but yeah we don't know if the user or another developer will want to put them into a collection using hashing in future . So ,yeah It is good practice to override `hashCode()` also.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [ArrayList.retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method like this

```
list1.retainAll(list2)
```

after this method list1 will containt only the data which are available in list2.

Comment: Even `retainAll` method uses `equals` method internally , So this won't keep any meaning if `equals()` is not overridden in the class definition.

Comment: no i have data in myData1 and data in myData2 but it is some data the same so i want in myData stock all of data of mydata1 and 2 but if it's been the same data in two arrays stock just one to not have repitition

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer) **Separate all.** Use logging and handle the exceptions.

1. If it is not a kind of dictionary attack, first do the SQL retrieving users with passwords.

   - Close result set, statement and connection.
   - Check the results.
2. Then get the telnet data.

   - Check the results.
3. Then do the comparison.

   - I hope you can see the deleted answer of @StinePike; he basically proposes `list1.retainAll(list2)` to remove all element in list1 that occur in list2.

---

I think you want to do the following. Outcommented is non-looping alternative.

```
// Add all myData2 and myData1 elements but not twice to myData.

// (1) Add myData2

myData.addAll(myData2);

// (2) Add myData1 when not in myData2

//myData1.removeAll(myData1);
//myData.addAll(myData1);
for (int i = 0; i < myData1.size(); i++)    
{    
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < myData2.size(); j++)    
    {
        if (myData2.get(j).equals(myData1.get(i)))
        {   
            found = true;
            break;             
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {      
        myData.add(myData1.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: look what i do but it gives me anything

Comment: myData2.retainAll(myData1);        
           for(int i=0;i<myData2.size();i++){
               System.out.print(myData2.get(i));
           }

Comment: so i do that and it gives me that he remove the same data  System.out.print(myData2.size());        
           myData2.retainAll(myData1);     
               System.out.print(myData2.size());

Comment: and when i do loop for for display the data of myData2 it gives me nothing myData2.retainAll(myData1);          
               System.out.print(myData2.size());
               for(int i=0;i<myData2.size();i++)
               {
                   System.out.print(myData2.get(i));
               }

Comment: hi i have table of two columns name and address i want sho the first data od second columns means the first addres and i use the 

    while (res.next()
     System.out.print(res.getString(2)) 

but it gives me the all data of second column how can i show the first

Comment: Sorry must pass, falling ill.